# programmatically add private queues in MSMQ

Tags: c#, command-line, msmq

I have list of over 20 queues that needs to be added as private queue in MSMQ.

Is there a way to do it using

1. Command Line
2. C# programming

If there is a way to do using some sort of script or .net programming then I could add it with out manually inputting it and causing typos.

Please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
using System.Messaging;

//...

void CreateQueue(string qname) {
   if (!MessageQueue.Exists(qname)) MessageQueue.Create(qname);
}
```

You can only create private queues on your local computer. For more information see: [Creating Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bzbb471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Richard, do you know how to set the permissions programatically as well in C#?

Comment: Use the AccessControlList to setup the permissions and then "queue.SetPermissions()".  Note that MessageQueue.Create will return the queue.

Comment: I found this article helpful regarding AccessControlList http://serializer.blogspot.com/2005/12/msmq-permissions-needs-touch.html

Comment: Hi, you can create public queues.

Comment: I would never approve the edit by @GregoryCurrie.  It should just be `using System.Messaging`.  I've changed the edit. I only do `using ... = ...` when I have name clashes.

Comment: @Richard Schneider All good. The important thing is the assembly is mentioned.

Comment: @GregroyCurrie, I've been on SO for a few years now and its not standard  practice to mention assemblies that can be assumed from the OP.  However, I think for newbies its a good idea.  Perhaps you should mention this to the higher gods on Meta?

Answer (score 2):

For command line, you can create a .vbs file with following content:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objInfo
Dim objQue
Dim objMsg
Dim strFormatName   ' Destination

strFormatName = "direct=os:.\private$\test"

Set objInfo = CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo")
Set objMsg = CreateObject("MSMQ.MSMQMessage")

objMsg.Label = "my message"
objMsg.Body = "This is a sample message."
objInfo.FormatName = strFormatName
set objQue = objInfo.Open( 2, 0 )

' Send Message
objMsg.Send  objQue

' Close Destination
objQue.Close

Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objInfo = Nothing

msgbox "Done..."
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this, however I only started working on them now.

To add to Richard's answer, you can create public queues.
you need the hostname though and admin access to that machine.

```
  public static MessageQueue CreatePrivate(string name) {
        string path = string.Format(@".\private$\{0}", name);
        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(path)) {
            MessageQueue.Create(path);
            return new MessageQueue(path);
        }
        return new MessageQueue(path);
    }

    public static MessageQueue CreatePublic(string hostname,string queuename) {
        string path = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", hostname,queuename);
        if (!MessageQueue.Exists(path)) {
            MessageQueue.Create(path);
            return new MessageQueue(path);
        }
        return new MessageQueue(path);
    }
}
```